# How can a class and companion object see private vals in Scala?

Tags: scala

```
object Foo {
  private val thing: String = "Yay"
}

case class Foo() {
  println(thing)
}
```

Is it possible for object Foo's `thing` to be visible only in class instances of Foo (shared visibility)? As shown, compiler complains

> ...thing in class is unresolved.

I'd rather not open it up to package-level visibility if it can be avoided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to import members of `object Foo` inside case class:

```
object Files {

  object Foo {
    private val thing: String = "Yay"
  }

  case class Foo() {
    import Foo._
    println(thing) //ok
  }
}
```

Using qualified name `Foo.thing` without import would also work.